# How can I use a macro to cut text to the clipboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm trying to write a macro which will cut the contents of the cell to the clipboard so I can paste it to another application. This don't work (it doesn't paste anything)...

```
Sub Macro5()

'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I should have explained, normal ol' cut and paste isn't going to work as it  doesn't *remove* the text from excel, only puts it into wherever you're pasting it from.

Comment: Is this for Excel, presumably?

Comment: See my updated answer.  I found VBA code which copies a string to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following as your macro.  Copy the code from the referenced webpage which defines the `ClipBoard_SetData` function

```
Sub Cut_Text()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = Selection.Value ' Get value of cell (Note: only single-cell selections supported)
    ClipBoard_SetData txt ' Copy contents of cell to clipboard
    Selection.Clear       ' Clear the contents of the cell
End Sub
```

***This code will only work for a single-cell selection.***

> [How To Use VBA Code To Copy Text To The Clipboard](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard)
>
> **Copy To Clipboard With Windows API**
>
> Below is the API workaround
>   suggested by Microsoft to get around the "SetText" bug.  It has three
>   parts: an API declaration section, a Function routine, and then I used
>   a similar subroutine macro to place the desired text into the
>   Clipboard.
>
> **UPDATE:** I have modified the API declarations to work with both 64-bit
>   and 32-bit versions of Microsoft Office
>
> ```
> 'Handle 64-bit and 32-bit Office
> #If VBA7 Then
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As LongPtr, _
>     ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
>     ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr, _
>     ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
> #Else
>   Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
>   Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
>   Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, _
>     ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
>   Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
>   Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
>   Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
>   Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
>     ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
> Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat _
>     As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
> #End If
>
> Const GHND = &H42
> Const CF_TEXT = 1
> Const MAXSIZE = 4096
>
> Function ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
> 'PURPOSE: API function to copy text to clipboard
> 'SOURCE: www.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192913.aspx
>
> Dim hGlobalMemory As Long, lpGlobalMemory As Long
> Dim hClipMemory As Long, X As Long
>
> 'Allocate moveable global memory
>   hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)
>
> 'Lock the block to get a far pointer to this memory.
>   lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)
>
> 'Copy the string to this global memory.
>   lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)
>
> 'Unlock the memory.
>   If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
>     MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted."
>     GoTo OutOfHere2
>   End If
>
> 'Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
>   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
>     MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted."
>     Exit Function
>   End If
>
> 'Clear the Clipboard.
>   X = EmptyClipboard()
>
> 'Copy the data to the Clipboard.
>   hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)
>
> OutOfHere2:
>   If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
>     MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard."
>   End If
>
> End Function
>
> Sub CopyTextToClipboard()
> 'PURPOSE: Copy a given text to the clipboard (using Windows API)
> 'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com
> 'NOTES: Must have above API declaration and ClipBoard_SetData function in your code
>
> Dim txt As String
>
> 'Put some text inside a string variable
>   txt = "This was copied to the clipboard using VBA!"
>
> 'Place text into the Clipboard
>    ClipBoard_SetData txt
>
> 'Notify User
>   MsgBox "There is now text copied to your clipboard!", vbInformation
>
> End Sub
> ```